# Dockerfile created for JBoss with MySQL image

Tags: mysql, docker, jboss

I am new in Docker concepts. I have created Docker image using dockerfile for JBoss and MySQL. I am trying to create image both are in one image.

Below is the my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_0.1-3.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
RUN dpkg -i percona-release_0.1-3.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
RUN apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install percona-server-server-5.6 -y
#CMD /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
CMD ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"]
RUN sudo apt-get install python-software-properties -y
RUN sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN /usr/bin/yes  | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN /usr/bin/yes | sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer -y
RUN java -version
RUN dpkg --get-selections | grep java

# enabling sudo group
# enabling sudo over ssh
RUN echo '%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers && \
sed -i 's/.*requiretty$/Defaults !requiretty/' /etc/sudoers

# add a user for the application, with sudo permissions
RUN useradd -m jboss
#RUN echo jboss | passwd jboss --stdin
RUN echo jboss:jboss | chpasswd
RUN usermod -aG sudo jboss
RUN wget http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip && sudo apt-get install unzip && sudo unzip jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip
RUN mv jboss-as-7.1.1.Final /opt/jboss && cd /opt/jboss/bin
# set environment
ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/jboss

# create JBoss console user
#RUN $JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh admin admin@2016 --silent
RUN  $JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh --silent=true admin admin@2016
# configure JBoss
RUN echo "JAVA_OPTS=\"\$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0\"" >> $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf
# set permission folder
RUN chown -R jboss:jboss /opt/jboss

# JBoss ports
EXPOSE 8080 9990 9999 3306

# start JBoss
ENTRYPOINT $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml

# deploy app
ADD sample.war "$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/"

USER jboss
CMD /bin/bash
```

Actually for only jboss is working fine .
After adding mysql installation commands into dockerfile. 
mysql was not starting in the container.But manually i am able to starting the mysql service
    i am able to entering container using bash shell and checking the services and noticed that  jboss ports are up but not mysql port. 
I am not understanding how to start mysql service in the container while building the image.

```
below are the my commands

docker build -t jbosstest1:devel .
docker run -p 8082:8080 -p 9992:9990 -p 3308:3306  jbosstest1:devel
root@docker:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                              NAMES
a95fd7f20036        jbosstest1:devel    "/bin/sh -c '$JBOSS_H"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        9999/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8082->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9992->9990/tcp   mad_kilby

root@docker:~# docker exec -it a95fd7f20036  bash

root@a95fd7f20036:/# netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4447            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5445            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9990            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3528          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5455            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53/java
udp        0      0 224.0.1.105:23364       0.0.0.0:*                           53/java
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57924           0.0.0.0:*                           53/java
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9876            0.0.0.0:*                           53/java
```

MySQL port was not up, and exported ports are listing to my machine (8082,9992 and 3308). Can any one explain to me how can I start MySQL service and JBoss server using dockerfile? I would like build my Docker image with JBoss and MySQL.

Comment: Still i am facing same issue .. please help me on this.. i want to run single container along with jboss and mysql...